# Novel: AI-assisted Dog Drives Car at Night

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to remember a science-fiction novel (may have been a shorter form) about an optimistic near-future, possibly written in the 1960's. A very small piece of the plot had to do with a family dog assisted by AI and a voice-box that developed a habit of going into the home's garage at night while the family was sleeping, climbing into a self-driving car and telling the car to take him for a drive out in the countryside, unbeknownst to the dog's owners. The dog may have been suffering an existential crisis.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some points of overlap with the following, but perhaps not enough to be a correct ID.

Self-driving cars are a major plot point in Roger Zelazny's *[The Dream Master](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?13717)*. Towards the end of it, a mutated, intelligence-enhanced, talking seeing-eye dog uses one of the self-driving cars to seek help for his mistress.

> "How did you get here?"
>
> "Drove. Know the co, or, din, ates... Left car, outside."

There is a reference to the dog driving the car on his own before this happens.

> "Have you been driving the car again?"
>
> "Yes"
>
> "After I told you not to?"
>
> "Yes."

*The Dream Master* also appeared in a shorter form called "He Who Shapes", but I am not sure if the ending is the same.

Comment: That might be the one, but I do remember the dog driving by himself at night for the sheer pleasure of doing so without his masters knowing.

Comment: That may have happened as well. I'll page though the book again. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for being so quick. I was about to look through my own boxes of paperbacks for the book.  I'll credit you with a hit on this one.

Comment: @GlennRay The ending is exactly the same.

Comment: Note that the dog in this book, a shepherd, is not AI enhanced; rather he has been genetically enhanced.  A mutie is how he is referred to.